# Is Seidel's algorithm on wikipedia page incorrect?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, graph

I am trying to use the python program from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seidel%27s_algorithm .

```
from numpy import matrix
def apd(A, n: int):
    """Compute the shortest-paths lengths."""
    if all(print(i,j)or A[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i != j):
        return A
    Z=A**2
    B=matrix([[1 if i != j and (A[i][j] == 1 or Z[i][j] > 0) else 0 for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)])
    T=apd(B,n)
    X = T*A
    degree = [sum(A[i][j] for j in range(n)) for i in range(n)]
    D = matrix([[2 * T[i][j] if X[i][j] >= T[i][j] * degree[j] else 2 * T[i][j] - 1 for j in range(n)]for i in range(n)])
    return D
maatriks=matrix([
         [0,0,1,0,0],
         [0,0,1,0,1],
         [1,1,0,1,1],
         [0,0,1,0,0],
         [0,1,1,0,0]])
print(apd(maatriks,5))
```

But I gives error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[PATH]/Seidel.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(apd(maatriks,5))
  File "[PATH]/Seidel.py", line 4, in apd
    if all(print(i,j)or A[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i != j):
  File "[PATH]/Seidel.py", line 4, in <genexpr>
    if all(print(i,j)or A[i][j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i != j):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py", line 193, in __getitem__
    out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Am I using the program wrongly or is the program itself incorrect?
[Here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15850-f18/www/scribes/lecture04.pdf) on page 9 seems to be the exactly same algorithm as is implemented in python.

Comment: i em sorry to say this but bug is almost 100%-ly in your code

Comment: the error can happen when you create reference cycle and then compare value to it self

Comment: AFAICT, the wikipedia version assumes that `A` is a `matrix` rather than a 2D array. So the `Z = A**2` and `X = T*A` actually perform matrix multiplication, not element-wise multiplication.

Comment: @JakubDóka, which parameter is reffering to itself?

Comment: That's not good Python/numpy code.  The `[i][j]` style of indexing is appropriate for nested lists.  It works with `ndarray`, but fails with `np.matrix`.  But the '*' and '**' appear to assume `np.matrix`.  But `np.matrix` use is now discouraged if not actually depricated.

Comment: @JakubDóka, you were wrong here is no reference cycle!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This implementation worked for me. The code provided on wikipedia has the indexing incorrect. when indexing a numpy matrix to get the *i'th* , *j'th* element you need to do `A[i,j]` not `A[i][j]`

```py
from numpy import matrix


def apd(A, n: int):
    """Compute the shortest-paths lengths."""
    if all(A[i, j] for i in range(n) for j in range(n) if i != j):
        return A
    Z = A ** 2
    B = matrix(
        [
            [1 if i != j and (A[i, j] == 1 or Z[i, j] > 0) else 0 for j in range(n)]
            for i in range(n)
        ]
    )
    T = apd(B, n)
    X = T * A
    degree = [sum(A[i, j] for j in range(n)) for i in range(n)]
    D = matrix(
        [
            [
                2 * T[i, j] if X[i, j] >= T[i, j] * degree[j] else 2 * T[i, j] - 1
                for j in range(n)
            ]
            for i in range(n)
        ]
    )
    return D

a = matrix(
    [
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
    ]
)
print(apd(a, 5))
```

Returns this.

```py
[[0 2 1 2 2]
 [2 0 1 2 1]
 [1 1 0 1 1]
 [2 2 1 0 2]
 [2 1 1 2 0]]
```

Is this the response you expect to see?

Comment: Yes, these are correct distances between the vertexes.

Comment: Awesome. Just be on the lookout for hitting recursion depth, which is an error I received. I did this by changing around the adjacency matrix.  Python has a limit to prevent stack over flows.  `import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())`